# How do you analyze an unbalanced fractional factorial design?

Tags: references, experiment-design, fractional-factorial

I'm interested in learning about unbalanced fractional factorial designs. If they are possible to analyze, what are the drawbacks to using them? Just usual loss of orthogonality? How does analyzing such an experiment differ when using ANOVA vs regression? As a side note, I'm looking at a $3^{4-1}$ design if that makes any difference.

Background: Some treatments were quite difficult to collect as setting up the equipment was time consuming and prohibitive. In contrast, certain treatments were easy to collect and naturally occurred in shifting the equipment about. Thus, it was known before hand that, for this reason, the design was to be imbalanced.

I'd love a book reference if possible where I can read more about this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Why do the imbalance occur? Was it planed that way, if so, why? Or did some experimental runs go wrong? That could maybe by itself be informative ... but to say more we need details and context on your specific case.

> How does analyzing such an experiment differ when using ANOVA vs
> regression?

It does not differ. ANOVA is just a special case of regression, with some traditional differences in terminology and presentation, but no substantial differences.

> I'm interested in learning about unbalanced fractional factorial
> designs. If they are possible to analyze, what are the drawbacks to
> using them?

The drawback is only the lack of balance itself, which implies a more complicated, less intuitive, analysis, and some loss of efficiency and robustness. Models for unbalanced fractional factorial designs are just unbalanced anova's, a faq here, see this [long list of answered questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=anova+unbalan*+answers%3A1). For more sepcific advice, you need to tell us **why** you got unbalanced.

Comment: Some treatments were quite difficult to collect. It was known before hand that, for this reason, the design was to be imbalanced.

Comment: Please add new information as an edit to the posts, not only as a comment. Not everybody reads comments! Then: **Why** the difficulty of collection? That might be important.  If this missingness is informative, for instance, then that must be handled, maybe modeled.

Comment: I added some details, thanks.